# How can I pass a single PyObject (created in a C++ backend) to an embedded Python Interpreter?

Tags: python, c++, c

Hi I am writing a new Python type defined as it follows:

```
typedef struct 
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    /* Type-specific fields go here. */
    int * value
} Noddy;
```

I have also defined all other methods and attributes needed as is described in: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html.

The thing is that I can create and use my new objects in Python without any problem but when I'm trying to create an object in C I cannot transfer to the Python Interpreter. I'm working with a backend in C++ and Python is embedded and then extended (extending embedded python) to provide further script functionality.

The main point is when I create the PyObject:

```
PyObject * pNoddy;
// Create Object
pNoddy= _PyObject_New(&pynoddy_PyNoddyType);
// Initialize Object.
pNoddy= PyObject_Init(pNoddy, &pynoddy_PyNoddyType);
```

Now on pNoddy I have a PyObject of the type defined previously. And I want to load it onto my Python Interpreter. For this purpose I have tried following code but it crashes.

```
PyObject *pValue, *pFunc;
// ("addNoddy") is a function defined in Python.
pFunc = PyString_FromString("addNoddy");
// VM is the main module of my system. pNoddy is the PyObject.
pValue = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(VM, pFunc, pNoddy);
/********************* NEVER REACH THIS POINT **********************/
Py_DECREF(pValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs like this

```
pValue = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(VM, pFunc, pNoddy, NULL);
```

From the docs:

> PyObject* PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(PyObject *o, PyObject *name, ...,NULL)
>
> *Return value: New reference. Calls a method of the object o, where the name of the method is given as a Python string object in name. It
>   is called with a variable number of PyObject* arguments. The arguments
>   are provided as a **variable number of parameters followed by NULL**.
>   Returns the result of the call on success, or NULL on failure.*